# Server error when attempting to log into Network Engineering Meta

Tags: bug, user-accounts, per-site-meta, 500-server-error

[image: Screen shot]

I haven't been able to access https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com since being directed there by a mod about a concern I had. This was nearly a week ago.

I constantly get...

> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site. It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault. Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified.

Have tried Firefox, Chrome both from an Australian and New Zealand IP. Other Stack sites (like this one) seem to work fine.

Edit: I cleared cache and I can see the site. When I try to log in with Google I get the same issue.

Comment: Works fine for me in Brisbane.

Comment: Working in Melbourne for me. What makes you think it's related to your location? Have you tried a VPN outside of AU/NZ that does work?

Comment: Yeah, I'd recommend what @ert says. From the looks of it, it may be some weird issue with your account.

Comment: After looking further into what happened, it seems there is indeed an issue with your account. Your Meta account here is indeed linked with your Network Engineering account, and you have a meta profile there, but for some reason when your post here was migrated to Network Engineering Meta, it didn't properly associate it with your account there (your username on the post there is a grayed-out non-link, which is typical if the user doesn't have an account on the destination site, even though you do).  The fact that your meta profile doesn't list your other communities seems to confirm this.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog any suggestion on what to do?

Comment: Looks like the only remedy at the moment is to [contact Stack Exchange](/contact). I've [asked a question](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1934/a-user-cant-access-this-per-site-meta-due-to-an-issue-with-their-account-their) on their meta asking for this issue to be resolved, and you should include a link to it in the email you write. (If you can't see that post, open it while logged out.)